# Django CMS - Call a cmsplugin in a template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms, django-tagging

**My problem**

With Django CMS 2.3.3, when creating a Page I use cmsplugin_picture* next to a couple of other cmsplugins. In my cms template, instead of doing:

```
{% placholder "content" %}  //calling the Django Page including all plugins...
```

I would like to call each cmsplugin seperately, but how would I do that?
I looked at Django tag template (filters) [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/) and also studied Django CMS template tags [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/advanced/templatetags.html), but neither seem to suggest that possibility. I have to say I am a beginner so I might not have connected the dots...

**What I try to achieve:**

In my template I have a IMG tag (outside of the `{% placeholder "content" %}` tag) which I want to populate with an image url that I define in my Page/cmsplugin_picture. So I am looking for a placeholder tag that allows me to grab that image. In my wildest dreams I would name it:

```
{% show_placeholder "content" request.current_page.get_cmsplugin_picture %}
```

**Obviously the above doesn't work, but does something like this exist?**

**I have also tried cmsplugin_filer, but to me it isn't necessarely more beneficial to fix this particular problem.*

EDIT:
What I mean by Page/cmsplugin_picture -> In a Django CMS Page you can select between your installed cmsplugins to add to a Page. In my case I select cmsplugin_picture and upload an image (within that plugin). This image I want to 'call' in my Django Template. So it is a not a static url, but dynamic.

Comment: I think I'm having trouble understanding the question. *"...that I define in my Page/cmsplugin_picture."* Do you want to hardcode the URL so that there's a default image in your image placeholder?

Comment: Thanks jmeas for your interest, I clarified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a second placeholder where your img tag is (and optionally limit the types and amount of plugins using `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` (http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.3.3/getting_started/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf).

Comment: Great it works! Thanks ojii

**Solution:**
_In Settings.py_
`CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'pica': {
        "plugins": ['PicturePlugin']
    },
}
// creates new placeholder option in admin`

_In my-template.html_
`{% placeholder 'pica' %} // displays full img tag`